# Why does Vmca decrease with increasing altitude?

Tags: general-aviation, multi-engine, v-speeds, theory

A question from a mock MEP class rating test:

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For airplanes with normally aspirated engines or turbocharged engine above their critical altitude, the engines produce less power as altitude increases as atmospheric air density decreases as altitude increases.  As power decreases, the operative engine requires less rudder authority to maintain directional stability due to the reduction in thrust, which allows the airplane to maintain directional authority at lower indicated airspeeds.  Therefore Vmca decreases as altitude increases.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind me what a turbocharged engine critical altitude is?

Comment: @ob318, it is the altitude above which the engine can't reach the manifold pressure redline. Manifold pressure is limited by the temperature gain from compression, which must remain below autoignition temperature of the mixture, and the strength of the pistons. Since the turbocharger can raise the pressure by some multiple, it could produce much more at low altitudes and the engine must be kept throttled to given MP red-line and thus constant power (power ~ MP × RPM). Above critical altitude the MP decreases even with wide open throttle and with it decreases power.

Comment: Wouldn’t rudder control authority also decrease with altitude  as well, for the same reason of reducing air density. Is it that the decrease in (engine) power is much greater in magnitude compared to the decrease in rudder control authority, with increased altitude?

Comment: For a given true airspeed, yes.  But Vmca is gauged in indicated airspeed which is proportionate to a constant ratio of dynamic to stagnant air pressures.